# How to hide some field in haml file without being parameters changed to different format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, rubygems, haml

i have one field in my haml file named #columns when i am trying to hide from the view, the parameters of the columns changing into different format.

I have used hidden to hide the columns , but the parmaters of columns are reformatting.

```
= f.input :columns, :as => :hidden
```

Is there way to get columns without getting format change

Expected:-

```
   columns:
   - day
   - Hello_name
```

Actual output:-

```
   columns: '["day", "Hello_name"]
```

Comment: Perhaps it is just me. But the one is a key with an array value in YAML format, the other is the same in Ruby. It is not clear to me how both versions are connected to a hidden input field?

Comment: like,is that the correct way to declare to hide the column and getting the parameters without format changed? or is any other way to hide the column from the view page and column parameters stay like Expected.

Comment: what do you mean by "hide the column" and what by "parameter format changed"

Comment: = f.input :columns, :as => :hidden
i previously used :as = > ;hidden , to hide the column field from the view ,as mentioned above , when i did that , as mentioned in question the expected parameters format is not coming, could you please give some solution to get the output as expected,Thanks , your help is appreciated